# Android PDF Writer (APW) not displaying PDF

Tags: java, android, pdf

I'm trying to use [APW library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/apwlibrary/) into my app but I cannot make it work. Also, I can't find any demo, how-to or full code example to guide me using this library. Here is what I've done so far:

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
</TextView>
```

**PDFWriterDemo.java**

```
public class PDFWriterDemo extends Activity {

    TextView mText;

    private String generateHelloWorldPDF() {
        PDFWriter mPDFWriter = new PDFWriter(PaperSize.FOLIO_WIDTH, PaperSize.FOLIO_HEIGHT);
        mPDFWriter.newPage();
        mPDFWriter.setFont(StandardFonts.SUBTYPE, StandardFonts.COURIER_BOLD);
        mPDFWriter.addText(150, 150, 14, "http://stackoverflow.com");
        mPDFWriter.addLine(150, 140, 270, 140);

        int pageCount = mPDFWriter.getPageCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
            mPDFWriter.setCurrentPage(i);
            mPDFWriter.addText(10, 10, 8, Integer.toString(i + 1) + " / " + Integer.toString(pageCount));
        }

        String s = mPDFWriter.asString();
        return s;
    }

    private void outputToScreen(int viewID, String pdfContent) {
        mText = (TextView) this.findViewById(viewID);
        mText.setText(pdfContent);
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdf);
        String pdfcontent = generateHelloWorldPDF();
        outputToScreen(R.id.text, pdfcontent);
    }
}
```

I'm calling `PDFWriterDemo` from my `MainActivity` like this:

```
Intent pdf= new Intent(MainActivity.this, PDFwriterDemo.class);
pdf.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(pdf);
```

And this is the output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to use APW library into my app but I cannot make it work

That is because you are trying to show a PDF file in a `TextView`. A `TextView` cannot display a PDF. If you want to display a PDF, use a PDF viewer app.

Comment: Fair enough. I've taken that code from the official page, so I thought it would work since the method says "outputToScreen". Anyway, I've executed this code into a real device and a .pdf has been created and I could open it with another application. So.. this code works. Thanks for the tip.